# How to get a list of inactive following (users) of instagram?

Tags: instagram-api

I am reading the API of instagram and couldn't find ways to get the date of the most recent activity (presumedly most recent login or most recent like or comment?) through its API (or I missed something).

It seems to be a feature in the app InstaGhost although once you remove a few users it becomes useless - regardless I am like to know how I can do similar thing.

PS. InstaGhost only allows me to remove these users on my phone and I have to tap two times per user to remove them - and it even charges users to be able to do it - and it will become useless after a removing a few users. I thought this is a simple feature and it should be available as a web app, and free. So I am making one.